# Follow current line in attribute table?

Tags: pyqgis, pyqt4

I would like to teach the QGIS map canvas to follow the current row of an attribute table. I found the method [`QgsAttributeTableView.currentChanged()`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtableview.html#currentChanged) as possible starting point, but unfortunately it's not a signal but a protected virtual method inherited from QTableView.

So I tried this in a python plugin, but it didn't produce any messages ([I think here is explained why](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/gotchas.html#access-to-protected-member-functions)):

```
    def watchTable(self, attTable):

    @pyqtSlot()
    def currentChanged(attTable, current, previous):
        bar = self.iface.messageBar()
        bar.pushMessage('my plugin',
                        'currentChanged: cur {}, prev {}'.format(current, previous),
                        bar.INFO, 5)

    # would this overwrite something existing?
    attTable.currentChanged = currentChanged
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I have some success catching the paint event, with Nathan's help. Current code looks like this:

```
def eventFilter(self, object, event):
    tv = self.followedTable
    if object == tv.viewport() and event.type() == QEvent.Paint:
        ci = tv.currentIndex()
        row = ci.row()
        if row != self.lastRow:
            # this should probably be outside the event filter (emit signal?)
            model = sip.cast(ci.model(), QgsAttributeTableFilterModel)
            fid = model.rowToId(ci)
            layer = model.layer()
            f = QgsFeature()
            layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest(fid)).nextFeature(f)
            g = f.constGeometry()
            c = g.centroid().asPoint()
            mc = self.iface.mapCanvas()
            ms = mc.mapSettings()
            mc.setCenter(ms.layerToMapCoordinates(layer, c))
            mc.refresh()
            self.lastRow = row
    return False

def watchTable(self, attTable):
    try:
        # here I get crashes/mini dumps
        self.followedTable.viewport().removeEventFilter(self)
    except:
        pass
    self.followedTable = attTable
    self.lastRow = -1
    self.followedTable.viewport().installEventFilter(self)
```

EDIT: My "Sync map and attribute table" plugin is available in QGIS official plugin repository, marked as experimental.